# How to hide a chart in vba

Tags: vba, excel

I want to hide chart for a particular value but make it visible for other values. Data for my chart is from cell(A,3) to cell(k,10).
Value of cell(A,3) is dynamic. As such, I want chart to be hidden for a particular value of A3.
I tried this code but it doesn't work:

```
Sub chart_visibility()
     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Activate
       If Range("A3").Value = "STATE_PROVINCE" Then
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Visible = False
       Else
        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Visible = True
      End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: try removing the "Application.Screenupdating = false. Thats basically telling excel, "Dont show me what youre doing"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quoting DDuffy here, the command `ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 2").Visible = False` should hide your chart.
I don't really know why even after `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` it wouldn't hide the chart. For me this seems to work just as well.
Maybe someone else got an Idea?